# Azure storage outage

Tags: azure, storage, share

We cannot connect to Azure storage shares using net use anymore.

We use the same script from day one that works , but today we just receive a message:

System error 5 has ocurred.

Access is denied.

We did with admin rights in 5 servers with no clue.

Is there any kind of Azure storage outage in Brazil South region?

Regards,

Juliano Souza

Comment: ask [@AzureSupport](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport)

Comment: You can see Azure status page or @azuresupport as Remus mentioned.We too faced the issue once,but it turned out our company interent had brief outage,Further you also can engage azure team with logs during the same time period

Comment: This question should be closed, as StackOverflow isn't the place for such questions. Even if there _were_ a transient outage, the question becomes instantly loses its value when the service is reachable again.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Azure Status](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) page. "Brazil South" seems to be working fine at the time of this answer.

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a point-in-time view of the Azure Status page.